# php- code make it small

Tags: php, image-uploading

I am trying to make this code small using for or while loop . It is working with the following code,I just want this to be small. 'ufile' is the input name.

```
if (!$_FILES['ufile']['name'][0]) 

{
    echo "Upload 1st file";

}

else

{

    // can this be in a for loop???
    $path1= "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];

    $path2= "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][1];

    $path3= "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][2];

    $path4= "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][3];

    $path5= "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][4];

    $path6= "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][5];

    $path7= "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][6];

    $path8= "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][7];

}
```

Comment: yes use for loop and make array for path

Comment: Can you pls help me out with the code snippet???

Comment: This is not difficult. Have you tried doing it yourself? If you have then please explain what it is you do not understand, so we can give you some pointers.

Comment: for ($i=0;$i<7;$++)
{
 $path[$i]  = "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i];
}

However,if number of files you uploaded will be dynamic,then you can use count instead of fix number in for loop ,that is

for ($i=0;$i<count($_FILES);$++)
{
 $path[$i]  = "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i];
}

Comment: No I didnt try still since I'm not able to understand what value is to be given for $i<' ' in the for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$path = array();
for($i=0;$i<=7;++$i)
    $path[$i]="../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i];
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against your current coding style. Life would be simpler if you just stored the paths in an array, e.g.

```
 $paths[1] = "../uploads/" . $_FILES['ufile']['name'][0];
 $paths[2] = "../uploads/" . $_FILES['ufile']['name'][1];
```

Then you could do something like this:

```
$paths = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    $paths[$i + 1] = $_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i];
}
```

But to answer your question, you can do something like this instead, which is very similar:

```
$paths = array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= 7; $i++) {
    $paths['path' . ($i + 1)] = $_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i];
}
extract($paths);
```

See the [extract doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) for more info about what's going on here

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**variable variables**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as well :

```
foreach(range(0,7) as $index){
    $varname  = "path".$index;
    $$varname = "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you want to do with those paths afterwards but here is my go at it. I would use the length of the array, assuming it doesn't always contain the same amount of file names.

```html
$paths = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['ufile']['name']); $i++)
{
    $paths[] = "../uploads/".$_FILES['ufile']['name'][$i];
}
```

Comment: This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: I have added the whole question as an answer in this post..Please read it.